# Show window titles in Unity's Application Switcher

Tags: 14.04, unity, application-switcher

Unity's default switcher shows applications' name while switching. I want this behavior when switching windows of same application.

Currently, as soon as the icon of an application having multiple windows is expanded, window titles are not shown by the switcher separately. Since I removed title bars to gain space, I need the switcher explicitly show the window title below the previews, etc.

Note: In CCSM, `Show live previews of windows in the Switcher` is unchecked but switcher still shows previews of multiple windows of an application.
`Timed automatic to show live previews in the switcher` is checked.